# TornadoFX key press listener issues

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

When I run the following code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(HelloWorldApp::class.java, *args)
}

class HelloWorldApp : App(HelloWorld::class)

class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = hbox {
        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY) { event ->
            println("pressed:"+event.character)
        }
    }
}
```

When I press any keys on my keyboard the println() is never called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a similar problem I came up with this, which looks simpler, but I do not yet understand any possible subtle differences between using the keyboard control versus explicit focus requesting.

```
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent
import tornadofx.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<HelloWorldApp>(args)
}

class HelloWorldApp : App(HelloWorld::class)

class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = hbox {
        keyboard {
            addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) { println(it.code) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply adding an `HBox` does not give it focus, and when it doesn't have focus it won't receive key events. You should override `onDock` and add the listener to the `currentScene` instead. If you really need to add the listener on the `HBox`, add the listener and request focus once the view has been docked:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<HelloWorldApp>(args)
}

class HelloWorldApp : App(HelloWorld::class)

class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = hbox {
        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY) { event ->
            println("pressed:" + event.character)
        }
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        root.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure :-)